# PHP array replace after matching value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an base array like below

```
$orgigal = [
          0 => [
            'month' => '02',
            'total_sum_coin' => 0,
          ],
          1 => [
            'month' => '03',
            'total_sum_coin' => 0,
          ],
          2 => [
            'month' => '04',
            'total_sum_coin' => 0,
          ],
    ]
```

Also have another replacement array like below

```
$replace = [
        0 => [
               'month' => '03',
               'total_sum_coin' => 10,
        ],
        1 => [
                'month' => '04',
                'total_sum_coin' => 20,
        ],
    
    ]
```

After use replace function

```
array_replace($orgigal,$replace)
```

It's replacing by key, I am trying to replacing it by value after match with months.

My desire output

```
$orgigal = [
          0 => [
            'month' => '02',
            'total_sum_coin' => 0,
          ],
          1 => [
            'month' => '03',
            'total_sum_coin' => 10,
          ],
          2 => [
            'month' => '04',
            'total_sum_coin' => 20,
          ],
    ]
```

Comment: where is your code for the same?

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use a for(each) loop, array_walk() or array_map()?

Comment: I am trying to use Array_map here but failed to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace on `month` it would have to be unique, so just index on that and replace:

```
$orgigal = array_replace(array_column($orgigal, null, 'month'),
                         array_column($replace, null, 'month'));
```

Or:

```
$orgigal = array_column($replace,  null, 'month') + array_column($orgigal, null, 'month');
```

If you don't want the `month` as keys after, then just use `array_values`.

Answer (score -1):

If you can slightly change your array structure you could use [arrray_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead of array_replace. Otherwise you could simply use the + array union operator, but remember to make the sum like replace + original, because duplicate keys will be taken from 1st operator
example from same page as merge:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
$result = $array1 + $array2;
var_dump($result);
?>
```

this results in:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "zero_a"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "two_a"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "three_a"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "one_b"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "four_b"
}
```

Comment: Sorry , I want to update not merge also by value not by key.